# Magento2.3 Undefined index: list_id in Stores/Save.php

Tags: magento2.3, mailchimp

I installed a Mailchimp integration plugin on our magento2.3 website and it does not seem to load the configuration page . When I look in the exception.log I get the below error

```
Undefined index: list_id in /vendor/mailchimp/mc-magento2/Controller/Adminhtml/Stores/Save.php on line 95
```

I am not sure how to fix this. I have tried reinstalling the plugin but that brings me to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

The MailChimp account needs to have an Audience/List for the Magento store to connect to. When you then add a MailChimp store in Magento, you can then select this store & list on the configuration page for the MailChimp module.